# Which niceness to give to prevent freezing?

Tags: cinnamon, process-priority, nice

If I wanted to give my main system, desktop cinnamon, the highest priority, which PID should I set this for?

The reason is because I have a program that runs for days and would hog up all the resources to a point where I can't even move my mouse.  It calls several programs on demand so its difficult to set which program to lower priority.  When it runs I can't do anything else.   Thus I'm wonder if I can just give my window the highest priority instead?  thanks!

Ahdee

Answer (score 0):

The process that eats up the most CPU in normal usage is probably the X server. First, find the pid (Process ID) of your X process:

```
ps aux | grep /usr/bin/X
```

This will give you a line starting with `root [pid] ...`.

Now, let's increase the priority:

`sudo renice -5 [pid]`

This sets the priority to 20 (the default priority) minus 5 (the nice value), resulting in a total priority of 15. The lower the priority number, the more often the process will be scheduled for processing. You can check the priority with the `top` command. Experiment until you are satisfied. However, `renice` is a dangerous command and may make your system unusable (until a reboot).